# How to add 15 days in String Date in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to add 15 days in my date string but I don't know How to do that? Please help me regarding that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the add method. Create a calendar object with the current date. And use the below method.

This should give you an idea

```
DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

objCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);
return objFormatter.format(objCalendarDup.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

You must parse the date by means of a [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html), then use a GregorianCalendar to do the maths:

```
    Date date = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).parse("12/31/1999");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);
    gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a `java.util.Date` and then use either `java.util.Calendar` or JODA time to do i
it.

A Date isn't a String.  Use the types that are available to you.  Convert the String into a Date using `java.text.DateFormat`.